# idea to resolve a simple task with php and jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a php script that is to retrieve employees names from the database and put them in an array ($array).

I also have a javascript code to do some animation which needs the total number of employees acquired as a parameter. In my case that becomes `parameter={0,1,2,...,array_count($array)-1}` 
THese numbers I would like will be used as a `class/id name` in each `div` I create in a loop

e.g

`<div class=<?php echo "employee_".parameter[i]; ?>`

I have no idea how this is supposed to be resolved. THerefore in my javascript code, I can only specify straight the array parameter as

`var parameter = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];`

because right now I know there are 8 items but in the future I won't.

Comment: Use `json_encode()` to pass your data to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

your php should `print json_encode($array)`

then in javascript, you should use a for loop to create a list of divs. then you'll have access to their IDs.

```
html = '';
for(var i = 0; i<someArray.length; i++) {
   html += '<div class="employee_'+i+'">...</div>';
}
```

Comment: What is somearray, could you clarify ? I am very new to this. How can just `print json_encode($array)` return what I need ?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using AJAX to get that php data. and if you are, then you can set your response data to a variable, interpret it as JSON, and I arbitrarily named it `someArray`... you'd need to tinker with your response data to get it into a format to your choosing... its a skill you must hone; its essential to everything you will be doing in this technology